# Content hovering Menu on page load after login

Tags: html, css

I have an administrative page that after login the content does not start with the margin of the menu making the transaction to stay in the right place, this only occurs when you log in and open the page with the menu the first time, it follows what happens:
[image: ERRADO]

[image: CORRETO]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow your question should contain a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without any code to work with your issue could any one of a million things causing it. Providing an _MVCE_ will help us narrow down and provide solutions/help with your particular issue.

Comment: In other words, provide some HTML, CSS, and/or Javascript that reproduces this problem.